# How does knockout container less syntax work? (is it evil?)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

We can find many examples and code using knockout ContainerLess syntax (even if I struggle to find proper documentation [from their site](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html)).

My first question formulation was "is it evil?", but I had to admit I do not really get how it can work and how it ensures the browser does not transform or simply removes/alters comment sections?

So, I change my question :

> How does it work (pre-processing, pre-rendering...)?

(and is it Evil? I can't help thinking that changing the nature of a comment is bad manner).

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. I say this because I believe I will not be the only one.

Comment: In other words: Is knockout containerless syntax a trick that developers should avoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Containerless control flow works my scanning the comments for comments that start with `ko`, and provide valid bindings. It is not "evil" in the sense that it is inefficient or an antipattern, if that's what you were asking.

If you are really interested in knowing, here is the [source code](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/blob/master/src/virtualElements.js). It is pretty straightforward though. It scans for the comments, parses out the bindings, and then passes them to the standard binding handlers.

Comment: Thanks for link to source. Very informative. A agree with not "Antipattern" but isn't that a huge hack like: I do not have appropriate syntax in JS so why not using the comments?

Comment: I have heard people make that argument, but they are making their own counterpoint. The containerless "container" has to exist in the HTML, and there isn't another way to put something in HTML that isn't HTML. It is a performant solution that *works*. I think that trumps any philosophical arguments.